# Is there a method to help make this Python logic run faster

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on a solution to grab data from a PLC sensor with **Python** and I was able to work out the syntax and such using [cpppo](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo) and that is working just fine as far as getting the data from the tag in a loop in a presumed serialized manner.

To test this new **Python** cpppo solution I've connected the machine that runs the **Python** logic to a PLC via a VPN tunnel and I have it [poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) a specific tag/sensor. This tag is also *polled* *and recorded* with a different ***non-Python*** solution that is connected to the local machine network via Ethernet.

---

### Question

Does anyone know a way I could potentially re-write this simply code below in a manner that I could force it to poll 3 or even 4 times in a second? Anything else that could be contributing to this?

- By contributing to "this", I am talking about the "other" or "non-Python" method seems to record **poll** responses from this same tag ***3 times in a second*** and the **Python cpppo** solution only seems poll records at ***a max of 2 times per second*** and thus missing a weight every now and then when there are 3 weight values in one second—sometimes there are only 2 per second so it's not always 3 values in a second but there are 3 in a second sometimes.

[image]

---

### The Data

The sensor data is returned enclosed in square brackets but represents weight in grams with decimal precision and below is a small sample of the raw data.

```
[610.5999755859375]
[607.5]
[623.5999755859375]
[599.7999877929688]
[602.5999755859375]
[610.0]
```

---

### Python Code

**Note:** *The **Python** logic will write the polled value from the sensor to a csv file but generates and inserts the time stamp record based on system date and time via* `datetime.now()` *but before that I convert the value to a string and then strip square brackets from the iterated values per* `str(x).replace('[','').replace(']','')` using the `str()` function.

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple
from datetime import datetime
import time, csv

CsvFile = "C:\\folder\\Test\\Test.csv"
host = "<IPAddress>"

while True:
    x, = proxy_simple(host).read("<TagName>")

    with open(CsvFile,"a",newline='') as file:
        csv_file = csv.writer(file) 
        for val in x:
            y = str(x).replace('[','').replace(']','')
            csv_file.writerow([datetime.now(), y])
#time.sleep(0.05)
```

---

### The Problem and Testing Results

When I compare the **Python** captured csv file records with the records from the other **non-Python** capturing method of the tag, the **Python** generated csv records are missing at times and often.

**Notable Details (just in case)**

- There is a second or less time stamp difference between these two systems since they generate the time stamp at capture time.
- This specific sensor can spit out three values in one second but NOT always; sometimes one a second, or two a second, or none in a second.
- The other method uses Java I think but this code is not accessible to compare logic.
- I'm using Python version `3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]` and from **Windows 10**.

> ### Results
>
> **Python Method CSV** (missing the correlated `606.6` value)
>
> ```
> 2018-04-12 13:56:42.249408,610.5999755859375
> 2018-04-12 13:56:42.909309,607.5
> 2018-04-12 13:56:43.559472,623.5999755859375
> 2018-04-12 13:56:44.259771,599.7999877929688
> 2018-04-12 13:56:44.910270,602.5999755859375
> 2018-04-12 13:56:45.541044,610.0
> ```
>
> **Other Method CSV Results** (contains the `606.6` value)
>
> ```
> 12/04/2018 13:56:41,610.6
> 12/04/2018 13:56:42,607.5
> 12/04/2018 13:56:42,623.6
> 12/04/2018 13:56:43,606.6
> 12/04/2018 13:56:43,599.8
> 12/04/2018 13:56:44,602.6
> 12/04/2018 13:56:44,610
> ```

**Problem Note:** *Python missed capturing the* `12/04/2018 13:56:43,606.6` *record whereas it was recorded from the other system. I suspect this is due to some small minuscule delay per this logic since I only ever see it missing values when compared to the other non-Python captured file.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key part of your code is:

```
while True:
    x, = proxy_simple(host).read("<TagName>")

    with open(CsvFile,"a",newline='') as file:
        for val in x:
            # ...
```

In pseudo code:

```
forever:
    create proxy
    open output file
    process values from proxy
```

You mention that the sensor might produce about 3 values per second.  If you look at the implementation of [`read()`](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo/blob/master/server/enip/get_attribute.py), what it does is set up a new reader object and yield all values from it.

You probably believe your code is running like this:

1. create proxy
2. open output file
3. process value
4. goto 3

But in fact, it is probably running like this:

1. create proxy
2. open output file
3. process value
4. goto 1

Each time you call `read()`, it yields the values it knows about at the time.  It does not wait for any new values to arrive.

Try this refactoring:

```
source = proxy_simple(host)
with open(CsvFile,"a",newline='') as file:
    while True:
        for message in source.read("<TagName>"):
            for val in message:
                # ...
```

The other error in your original code is this:

```
x, = proxy_simple(host).read("<TagName>")
```

If `read()` returns multiple values, you only use the first one.  That's why there are two `for` loops in my proposed code above.

Then you will only open the input and output once per program run, not once per message.

Comment: `for val in message` iterates over the message, which is a list or array.  So each value has no square brackets.  If the message has just one value, like `['hello']` then iterating over the message gives you the string `'hello'` as the only loop iteration.  If you're sure the message always has a single value, you can do `val = message[0]` instead of `for val in message`.