# Why does this AssertionError exception not continue

Tags: python, python-3.x

### What I Have

I posted the correlated question [Is there a method to help make this Python logic run faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803896/is-there-a-method-to-help-make-this-python-logic-run-faster) a few days ago and I've extended on this logic for my testing needs after getting a confirmed solution.

For some reason I cannot figure out how to tell this Python as it's running if it gets an `AssertionError` to print out `Assertion Error` and then `continue` back with the logic again.

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple
from datetime import datetime
import time, csv, sys

host = "<PLC IP Address>"
TagName = "Tag Name"
RootCsvFile = "X:\\Some\\Folder\\Path\\"
source = proxy_simple(host)
prev = None

def csvwrite(v):
    with open(v[2],"a",newline='') as file:
        csv_file = csv.writer(file)
        csv_file.writerow([v[0],v[1]])

def ExecLoop(pr):
    prev = pr   
    while True:

        for message in source.read(TagName):

            try:
                val = message[0]
                timestr = str(datetime.now())
                if val != prev:
                    prev = val
                    YYYYMMDD = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
                    CsvFile = RootCsvFile + TagName + "_" + YYYYMMDD + ".csv"
                    print(timestr, val, CsvFile)
                    csvwrite([timestr, val, CsvFile])

            except AssertionError:
                print("Assertion Error")
                continue           
ExecLoop(prev)
```

---

### The Problem

Since this is getting data from a PLC machine network via a VPN connection, whenever the VPN has a disruption and is not able to be accessed via the Python, the below error occurs and it seems like the `except AssertionError:` is not doing what I've asked it to do and just get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"~\GetTag-ToSQLDB&CSVEFile.py", line 63, in <module>
      ExecLoop(prev)   File "~\GetTag-ToSQLDB&CSVEFile.py", line 46, in ExecLoop
      for message in source.read(TagName):   File "~\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\get_attribute.py",
line 431, in read
      for val,(sts,(att,typ,uni)) in reader:   File "~\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\get_attribute.py",
line 606, in read_details
       depth=self.depth, multiple=self.multiple, timeout=self.timeout )): File
"~\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py",
line 1393, in operate

  for idx,dsc,req,rpy,sts,val in harvested:   File "~\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py",
line 1270, in pipeline 
complete, requests ) 

AssertionError: Communication ceased before harvesting all pipeline responses:   0/  1
```

### What I'd Like

I'd like for it to keep retrying whenever there is an `AssertionError` since typically when there is an issue with connectivity, it's a short few second blip or else a couple minutes for an automated weekly power cycle of a network device on the client side of the VPN which the Python is running.

- **My Question:** How can I get the `except AssertionError:` logic in this process to print something and then go back and try looping or whatever again?

  - At the moment of the error, the process halt and has the *traceback* detail on the screen as posted in **The Problem** section of this question.

**My Assumptions**

I'm assuming the problem is related to:

- The `AssertionError` handling being defined in the `client.py` file as specified in the *traceback* error and that superseding the scripted `except AssertionError:` logic in the script.
- The `Try:` and `Exception:` logic being within a `while True` loop and then within a `for` loop within the `while True` loop.

---

### Other Details (Just In Case)

- This process is using the [cpppo](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo) package.
- I'm using Python version `3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]` and from **Windows 10**.
- I am running this process right from `IDLE` as I'm testing and not as a compiled package or anything like that. So the logic I posted is saved as a `py` file and then when opened in `IDLE` I execute it pressing `F5`.
- The "assumed" correlated `client.py` logic related to the `AssertionError` (see line 1269):

  - The logic shared here [clienty.py](https://codeshare.io/amNexk) since too big for my post.

Comment: Not a big deal, but for future reference, format your tracebacks, and anything else you see on the console as code. It makes the indentation come out much nicer than a variable-width font.

Comment: You should be finding the source of the `AssertionError` and *fixing* it, not simply acknowledging it and moving on.

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac. The other comment I made was stupid :) Don't pay any attention to that.

Comment: @chepner. I think OP is making a reasonable case for the treatment of the error being well thought out. The source of the error is expected hiccups on the remote end. Logging the error for future reference is about all you can do at that point.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah, I missed that. Seems like a terrible exception to raise, but indeed, that's out of the OP's hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AssertionError` occured in the `source.read(TagName)` call. you need to wrap this with your `try` `except` block:

```
while True:
    try:
        for message in source.read(TagName):   # Note that this connection might be broken after the error. 
            val = message[0]
            timestr = str(datetime.now())
            if val != prev:
                prev = val
                YYYYMMDD = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
                CsvFile = RootCsvFile + TagName + "_" + YYYYMMDD + ".csv"                       print(timestr, val, CsvFile)
                csvwrite([timestr, val, CsvFile])
     except AssertionError:
         print("Assertion Error")
         continue
```

Comment: I hope this will fix your problem :)

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac Emulate == Unplug the ethernet for a second?

Comment: I accepted your answer merely because you answered first and were right—putting the `for` loop within the `try` made it work as expected. I thought I tried some variation of this so not sure if something was different or what then but you also included the example of the code I provided and how to incorporate the suggested solution so nice job. I gave +1 already to both answers as both are correct, you were faster and gave suggested syntax to incorporate into the code example I provided so I accepted your answer for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

The traceback says it all: your `except` block is not in a place where it can see the exception at all. Specifically, look at the line

> ```
> for message in source.read(TagName): File "~\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\get_attribute.py", line 431, in read
> ```

The error is in your `for` loop, but the `try` is inside the loop. You had the right idea wrapping everything in a `while True`. The solution is to move the `for` *inside* the `try`.